# Good performance on both training set and validation set, but poor performance on the test set

Tags: neural-networks, python, conv-neural-network, keras

I'm building a CNN to classify the American Sing Language fingerprints. During training and validation it works very well, with accuracy going up to 95% and loss down to 10% on both. However, when it comes to the test set, even though the accuracy is still pretty good (80%) the loss is very high. I was wondering how could that be possible? Also, I tried to implement the same model with 20 epochs and 50 epochs, and on the test set they get the same exact accuracy and loss.

```r
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True,
                               validation_split = 0.2)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_train',
    target_size=(64,64),
    batch_size = 10,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical')

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_test',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 10,
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = 'categorical')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'asl_alphabet_train',
    target_size = (64,64),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    subset = 'validation')

#Found 87000 images belonging to 29 classes.
#Found 116 images belonging to 29 classes.
#Found 17400 images belonging to 29 classes.

thirdExperiment = classifier.fit(
    training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = training_generator.samples // 10,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // 10,
    shuffle = True,
    epochs = 20)
```

I'd like to add that the structure of the directories 'asl_alphabet_test' and 'asl_alphabet_train' is the same.
These are the accuracy and loss graphs:

[image: accuracy graph]

[image: loss graph]

Then if I call

```r
test_loss, test_acc = classifier.evaluate(test_generator)
```

I get:

```r
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 27ms/step - loss: 4.7849 -   
           accuracy: 0.8000
```

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

edit: I should clarify that the dataset consists of around 30000 pictures for the training set and around 100 pictures for the test set. Could it be this huge dimension gap causing the problem?

Comment: are you trying to optimize some hyperparameters? if so, which? if not, why do you have both a validation and test set?

Comment: This is for a university project. The professor specifically asked us to split into train/validation/test. So far i've been adjusting some hyperparameters like loss function, epochs and batch size but lowest loss i've got was still over 2.5.

Comment: mmmh... have you checked that all the sets (train, validation, test) are balanced? and that the validation and training set do not overlap? i.e. shouldn't the training generator only be trained on the subset = 'train'? is this also happening with other training/validationn/test data? I would also suspect that the sample size for the test set (116) is much smaller than what used in the train and validation sets (17400)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I believe they did overlap. I added subset = 'training' in the generator and now they are giving me completely different results, validation accuracy is stuck at 50% while training is going above 90%, at this point i think it's overfitting

Comment: exactly! or at least, your interpretation about overfitting seems plausible to me

Comment: n=100 is far too small for the test set.  The imbalance in size between training and test is not the problem; it's the absolute sample sizes that is important.   From n=100 your accuracy measure will have a precision of at worst 0.1 out of a 0-1.0 range.